# SQL GROUP BY selecting

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is my code:

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user_id = '$user_id' GROUP BY from_user_id ORDER BY read,sent_date DESC")`

and here is my table structure

[image]

I use the `GROUPY BY from_user_id` statement to briefly show a list of "conversations" instead of every single message. Like this

[image]

**But**, as you can see in the image, the top two are the wrong way round, the first one says "1 week ago" and the one below says "2 days ago". The reason for these being in the wrong order is due to the `GROUP BY from_user_id` statement. Because it groups all the messages from that user and it wont have the the most recent time on it.

So my question is:

**How can I** `GROUP BY from_user_id` **by the most recent record?**

Comment: Which database software?

Comment: Just retagged it MySQL. It must be, because of the `mysql_query` statement in the included PHP code, and because only MySQL lets you abuse GROUP BY semantics in this way. :S

Comment: Grouping by from_user_id means that there will be one row output for posts from that user, regardless of how many conversations (s)he is involved in. Does your table have a conversation ID field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
SELECT *,MAX(id) as OrderField FROM messages WHERE to_user_id = '$user_id' 
 GROUP BY from_user_id 
 ORDER BY OrderField DESC,read
```

Answer (score 6):

You can not `SELECT` columns not listed in the `GROUP BY` or otherwise [allowed functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). This is [how `GROUP BY` works](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php).

Although most other SQL flavors would fail on such a query, MySQL doesn't. Instead it provides *arbitrary* results - what you are seeing.

You can solve this a few different ways. For example:

- `SELECT` the *ids* of the latest user conversations using `GROUP BY` in a separate query.
- Do it all in one query by sub-selecting the *ids* or `JOIN` the set of *ids*.

Answer (score 2):

Since MySQL doesn't support windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Messages 
where id in (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM messages GROUP BY from_user_id) 
ORDER BY sent_date, read
```

The subquery will only return the newest message id for each user. I'm assuming your auto_increment corresponds with the order the messages are sent in. Even if it's not the exact logic you might want, this is a general technique to get a specific subset of values from grouped records that works in MySQL.